# iFrame in IE11 - background messed up

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to iframe this site http://interimincomemodel.com/reps/eugeny/fastsuccess/ into this one http://interimincomemodel.info/fastsuccess/

When I open index.htm on my PC with IE11 the iframe just looks like the original site.

But when I upload it on the server, the background is messed up in IE11: background image is not fit to screen, headlines are not highlighted, email boxes are not rounded.

Also when trying to iframe this website

interimincomemodel.com/reps/eugeny/

into

interimincomemodel.info

the video player controls bar in the iframe is much larger and the last button "play full screen" goes outwards and can't be clicked. It happens in every browser.

I'm using this code:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Interim Income Model</title>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding 0;
    overflow:hidden
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="http://interimincomemodel.com/reps/eugeny/" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" marginheight="9px" marginwidth="100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
  </body>

</html>
```

What can be causing the issues?

Thanks

Comment: both look exactly the same on IE11 for me

Comment: thanks Fabio, maybe it's a matter of OS or browser version